# There's any way to know what backups and or disk images Windows have?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, backup

I want to know from what dates are backups availables.

If I remember well with Windows 7 you can see the dates from where you can revert the PC to a know state. I can't find that in Windows 10 21H1

Also, There's any difference between a backup and Windows disk images?
Because I remember that I enabled like 2 months ago disk image for C: and now Windows says that there's no backup configured for any disk. How?

So now I don't know if I need to go back to a previous state I will can do it or no.
That's no a reliable system.

In my System event log there's a couple of "volsnap ID 33" that says that the older instantaneous disk image was removed to save space.

I don't want that.
How I configure it?

Comment: Your post is very confusing - not advising what software you used to make the backups makes a response hard. You might also want to advise exactly what you are trying to achieve (Documents, Documents+Progs, Recovery Image, Snapshot, PITR,  something else?)

Comment: @davidgo Windows itself is the software. You can roll back to a previous state. In W7 you have a calendar to see the dates where you or the system did a backup.